# gluCylinder with glTranslate

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having a problem where I've made a cylinder with following code, and I've been trying to move it (back, so that the center of it is where the grey beam is).

However, the output is not moving the cylinder at all, and I'm failing to spot what the issue is?

```
GLfloat plane[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, plane);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 3.0f, -11.0f);
        GLUquadricObj *quad = gluNewQuadric();
        gluCylinder(quad, 2, 2, 22, 30, 30);
    glPopMatrix();
glEnd();

glFlush(); /* Complete any pending operations */
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `glBegin` and `glEnd` calls. None of the functions you called there are allowed between those two commands.

Comment: Oh right, i see
So basically, begin/end should always be the innermost thing then?

Comment: @Astantos: yes. And here, I believe, `gluCylinder` already calls them.